KeyError: "Registering two gradient with name 'ReduceDataset'! - Tensorflow Keras import error
I'm working on a classification task by creating a simple network with keras. When I try to import the necessary packages
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier

I get the error you see below:
KeyError: "Registering two gradient with name 'ReduceDataset'! (Previous registration was in register /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/registry.py:65)"

starting from:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[126], line 1
----> 1 from tensorflow import keras
      3 from keras.models import Sequential
      4 from keras.layers import Dense

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py:45
     42 from tensorflow.python import tf2 as _tf2
     43 _tf2.enable()
---> 45 from tensorflow._api.v2 import __internal__
     46 from tensorflow._api.v2 import __operators__
     47 from tensorflow._api.v2 import audio

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/__internal__/__init__.py:11
      9 from tensorflow._api.v2.__internal__ import decorator
     10 from tensorflow._api.v2.__internal__ import dispatch
---> 11 from tensorflow._api.v2.__internal__ import distribute
     12 from tensorflow._api.v2.__internal__ import eager_context
     13 from tensorflow._api.v2.__internal__ import feature_column

...
These are the versions I have installed (I am working on macOS):
tensorflow 2.16.1
keras 3.3.3
scikeras 0.13.0
scikit-learn 1.4.2


You should not mix keras and tensorflow.keras.

Hi @ all.m , It seems you're facing a version compatibility issue between TensorFlow and Keras. TensorFlow and Keras have specific dependency requirements that need to be aligned for everything to work properly. The versions you're using might be causing a conflict or problem with their interaction.Check Compatibility:

Make sure that the versions of TensorFlow, Keras, and Scikeras you are using are compatible with each other. For the versions you have:
1.TensorFlow 2.16.1 is compatible with Keras 2.16.1 (but not with Keras 3.x.x), as TensorFlow 2.x includes Keras integrated as tf.keras.
2.Scikeras 0.13.0 should be compatible with TensorFlow 2.x.
